# How to advance lab assistants to researchers?

Tags: anno-2070

I can't find a list of needs for lab assistants. I gave them everything (they have carbon to upgrade). What else am I missing? I read researched on the internet and couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Their demands consist of energy drinks, fish and Functional Food,
they need to be in a range of a laboratory they have road connection to and finally taxes need to be at the lowest level.

You also must make sure that ascension rights are not disabled at your city center.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make full all of their needs. comunication food activity ect. and make the tax rate lover

Answer (score 0):

You must have carbon in your warehouse/depot to advance them!

Comment: he already mentions the assistants having carbon to upgrade.